# Append leading zeros to a field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to append leading zeros when the length of the integer is lesser than 7 digits. If the length of the integer is more than or equal to 7 digits it should return the actual integer. I've tried sql like below

```
select to_char(123456, 'fm0000000');
to_char 
---------
0123456
(1 row)
```

When the number of digits was > 7 it returns below string

```
select to_char(12345678, 'fm0000000');
to_char 
---------
#######
(1 row)
```

How can I get the exact integer when the number of digits greater than 7? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lpad function plus CASE statement:

```
select
  case
    when length(123456::text) < 7 then lpad(123456::text, 7, '0')
    else 123456::text
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lpad()`:

```
select (case when len(123412345::text) >= 8 then 123412345::text
             else lpad(123412345::text, 8, '0')
        end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. According to the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) lpad will truncate the right of the string when length of the string is more than specified length which is 8 in your case. The integer is dynamic in my case.

Comment: @Gomathi . . . I particularly hate it when I actually test solutions and miss something.